# A Mutex for inter-threading usages in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

I want a Mutex in Java which let me to wait on it in a thread and release it in another thread. I know that I can use a Semaphore with capacity of 1 but the problem is that the "acquire()" method throws "InterruptedException". Is there any special synchronization way for this purpose in Java?

Comment: Why is it a problem that interrupted exception can be thrown?

Comment: Is there something wrong with just using a synchronized block on any old object?

Comment: @Enno Shioji: I want to make sure I can acquire a permit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, Semaphore provides this method for you :)

[public void acquireUninterruptibly()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquireUninterruptibly%28%29)

> Acquires a permit from this semaphore, blocking until one is
>   available. Acquires a permit, if one is available and returns
>   immediately, reducing the number of available permits by one.
>
> If no permit is available then the current thread becomes disabled for
>   thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until some other thread
>   invokes the release() method for this semaphore and the current thread
>   is next to be assigned a permit.
>
> If the current thread is interrupted while waiting for a permit then
>   it will continue to wait, but the time at which the thread is assigned
>   a permit may change compared to the time it would have received the
>   permit had no interruption occurred. When the thread does return from
>   this method its interrupt status will be set.

Answer (score 1):

`InterruptedException` is not an issue, just wrap it in a loop:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        break;
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        //swallow, continue;
    }
}
```

However this code is not very safe and elegant, but will work providing that you "*want to make sure you can acquire a permit!*"

Comment: If Thread.currentThread().interrupt() in done in the catch clause I'd say it's pretty much the best way to handle this (besides using the acquireUninterruptibly method).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a code in which a thread is going to wait then you will definitely have to handle interrupted exception unless you are using synchronized block. Also, What is the problem with interrupted exception?

Answer (score 0):

**ThreadA**

```
volatile boolean waitCondition = true

synchronized(lockObject) {
  while (waitContidion) {
    lockObject.wait();
  }
}
```

**ThreadB**

```
synchronized(lockObject) {
  waitCondition = false;
  lockObject.notifyAll();
}
```

or use Condition/Signal on Lock instances.

Correct handling of InterruptedException is very important, at least you **must** set it's interrupted flag with **Thread.currentThread().interrupt()** method in catch block.